# List imported watch-only adresses

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, watch-only

I can import addresses without private key just to track incoming transactions as it is provided in RPC calls :
https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.10.0#watch-only-wallet-support

But how can i see my previously imported addresses? (With or without RPC)

Bonus : Is there any proper way to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I've found a workaround by adding label on importing :

```
bitcoin-cli importaddress <address> my_imported_address_list
```

Checking my label on listing :

```
bitcoin-cli getaddressesbyaccount "my_imported_address_list"
```

This solves my problem for now. But still searching for better answer where i dont need to label my own imported addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[`listreceivedbyaddress`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.19.0/rpc/wallet/listreceivedbyaddress/) can list all addresses (including watch-only) that haven't received, if used as below:

```
listreceivedbyaddress 0 true true
```

While this would exclude watch-only addresses:

```
listreceivedbyaddress 0 true false
```

And their outputs could be compared to find watch-only addresses